# How to get data from a html5 web form on a controller asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I have an web app and it has a controller without a model. I'm am trying to get some information (in this case `dateFrom`) and I want to be passed in a method (of type `ActionResult`). The method it has the following signature `GetInfo(DateTime dateFrom)`. Any ideas?

The code from razor is something like this:

```
<form method="post" action=@Html.ActionLink("GetInfo", "GetInfo", new  {dateFrom=getFromUser})>
    <input name="dateFrom" type="date"  />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: the code from razor is something like this:
<form method="post" action=@Html.ActionLink("GetInfo", "GetInfo", new  { dateFrom=getFromUser})>
    <input name="dateFrom" type="date"  />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your code up like this instead:

**In razor view:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetInfo", "MyController"))
{
    <input name="dateFrom" type="date"  />
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

**In `MyController` controller:**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetInfo(string dateFrom)
    {
        var test = (DateTime)dateFrom;
    }
}
```

dateFrom should automatically be populated with the date supplied by the user. If they do not supply a format that can be converted by .Net, it will be null.

Answer (score 2):

You can access dateFrom like this,

```
public ActionResult GetInfo()
{
    string sFromDate = Request.Form["dateFrom"];
    return View();
}
```

You can further convert sFromDate to `DateTime` object.